# How to count number of taps per second

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want my app to be able to count the number of taps every second. I assume this would have something to do with `touchesBegan:...`, but that doesn't work on a button, does it? Anyway, how would I measure the number of taps per second?
I think I could do it manually using a counter which resets every second but I was wondering if there is a better way.
Would it add the values to an array? And if so, would I be able to calculate an average excluding 0's?

My current code.

```
-(void) timer:(NSTimer *)averageTimer {
    if(tapCountInLastSecond != 0) {
        secondsElapsed++;
        averageTapsPerSecond += tapCountInLastSecond / secondsElapsed;
        tapCountInLastSecond = 0;
        NSLog(@"Average: %f", averageTapsPerSecond);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's quite simple, depending on what you want to do, but first, how do you plan to stop the tap count ? and what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to calculate the average taps per second excluding when no taps are made and use that to position an image on the screen.

Comment: If you're going to stop counting time when no taps are made that won't work, you need to have a timer that's always on, I'm imagining it like  you have to tap faster to move an image up, and when you don't tap the image starts moving down again, am I getting it right ?

Comment: Show some code you are trying to get to work

Comment: I don't want it to go back down, its odd I know.

Comment: "How to count number of taps per second" - you divide the number of taps by the elapsed time, perhaps?

Comment: SHERRIECRANE Check out the comments on my answer, the solution is there by @erkanyildiz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your viewController put those counters

```
int   tapCountInPastSecond = 0;
float averageTapsPerSecond = 0;
int   secondsElapsed       = 0;
```

Then add this method that invokes when you the screen or tap a button

```
- (void)incrementTapCount
{
    tapCountInPastSecond++;
}
```

Create a timer that will fire every second, doing it's calculations, then resets the tap count

```
- (void)timerActions
{
    secondsElapsed++;
    averageTapsPerSecond = (averageTapsPerSecond*(secondsElapsed-1) +tapCountInPastSecond) / secondsElapsed;
    tapCountInpastSecond = 0;
}
```

Now you can init your timer like that:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerActions) userInfo:Nil repeats:YES];
```

Then at any point you'll be able to get the average Taps/Second by reading the value `averageTapsPerSecond`

Hope this make sense to you

Comment: I implemented that. Yet the average can increase but not decrease e.g if the average if 5 and I click once per second the average will not go down. Ill edit my post to show you the code.

Comment: Even removing my if statement the average cannot go down still.

Comment: to get correct average value change it like this: averageTapsPerSecond = (averageTapsPerSecond*(secondsElapsed-1) +tapCountInPastSecond) / secondsElapsed;

Comment: @SHERRIECRANE of course, that's my mistake, basically the problem is that `averageTapsPerSecond` will be incremented by 0 if you don't tap, giving this behaviour, you can do exactly as @erkanyildiz says this will make it work !

Can you edit my answer @erkanyildiz so you get credit for the change ?